# PHP not displaying correctly in HTML

Tags: php, html, arrays, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a drop down box that is populated by an array. When I view my code the browser just displays pieces of the php code.

Here is what the browser displays:

```
'; foreach ($array as $value) { $html .= '
$value
'; } $html .= ''; return $html; } ?>
```

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<?php

$cities = array( 'San Francisco', 'San Diego', 'Los Angeles');

function createDropDown($name, $array) {

  $html = '<select name=$name>';

  foreach ($array as $value) {
    $html .= '<option value="$value">$value</option>';
  }
  $html .= '</select>';
  return $html;
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<form>

<?php
createDropDown("cities", $cities);
?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You sure your server supports PHP?

Comment: Future reference: you can only embed variables in strings if you use double quotes. Otherwise, you'll need to concatenate like @AlienWebguy did below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your server isn't configured to treat .php files as PHP scripts, and is serving them up as html/plaintext. If you view-source the page this is happening on, you'll probably get the full PHP source code. The `<?php` is seen as an opening HTML tag, which isn't closed until just before the foreach loop, so all the intermediate text/code is "hidden" in HTML view.

Answer (score 2):

You need to echo your output as well.  You build the string but never output.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<?php

$cities = array( 'San Francisco', 'San Diego', 'Los Angeles');

function createDropDown($name, $array) {

  $html = '<select name="' . $name . '">';

  foreach ($array as $value) {
    $html .= '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
  }
  $html .= '</select>';
  return $html;
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<form>

<?php
echo createDropDown("cities", $cities);
?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$html = '<select name=$name>';
```

to

```
$html = '<select name="' . $name. '">';
```

Change

```
$html .= '<option value="$value">$value</option>';
```

to

```
$html .= '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value. '</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

`'` doesn't parse, but `"` does.

```
 $html = "<select name=$name>";
```

will do it.